# Static HTML Page without Header/Footer

Tags: angular

I want to display some static HTML page in Angular but that should not contain any header/footer and also the URL like **http://localhost:4200/check** not **http://localhost:4200/check/index.html**
I have tried multiple links:

1. Added file in asset folder that is working fine but I need to give index.html in the URL so that is not required. I need URL with HTML file name like **http://localhost:4200/check** (only folder name)
2. Added file as component (e.g check/index.html) but access through **http://localhost:4200/check** but this is not working on other systems and even after publishing.
3. Header/Footer we are using in almost 50 component so cannot change a lot of setting in routing.module.
4. { path: '**', component: check } -- this is also not working

Comment: You can create a new component `check` and add route `check` in check component you can add your static HTML don not add header, footer component.

Comment: i did that but still adding the masters value and also performance is not consistant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved. Just need to save the HTML static file in the assets folder then you can call it from any component.

Comment: Instead of calling from angular component, is there a way to just render static html file, that has its own body. this html file is stored under a folder in `assets` folder.