# Jhipster page without header footer

Tags: java, jhipster

I'd like to have a full HTML page (with body) in Angular that should not contain any Jhipster header / footer but while still using Jhipster services / resources.

I have a fully working component that I'd like to put on this page. I've tried putting my page in src/main/resources/static as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63556650/static-html-page-without-header-footer) but no way: the header and footer still display.

To sum up, I'd like to have a full Jhipster component in a page without Jhipster decorations.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just search for FooterComponent and jhi-footer and remove them.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the

```
<jhi-footer></jhi-footer>
<jhi-page-ribbon></jhi-page-ribbon>
<router-outlet name="navbar"></router-outlet>
```

in

```
/src/main/webapp/app/layouts/main/main.component.html
```

For your own component you could use the home.component located in

```
/src/main/webapp/app/home/home.component.html
```